# Autofac and Nancy

Tags: .net, autofac, nancy

The following program using Autofac in conjunction with Nancy does not launch the default Nancy server correctly.

```cs
using Autofac;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;
using System;

namespace NancyExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Register(c => new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:8080"))).SingleInstance();

            using (var container = builder.Build())
            {
                NancyHost host = container.Resolve<NancyHost>();

                // this fails with:
                // Exception thrown: 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' in System.dll
                // Exception thrown: 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' in System.dll
                // Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
                // Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll

                // this works:
                // NancyHost host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));

                host.Start();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When resolving NancyHost via Autofac, it appears that an error comes deep within .NET's HttpListener. There doesn't seem to be good details on this exception. Visiting http://localhost:8080 results in no connection.

Instantiating NancyHost myself works fine.

Using:

- Autofac 4.3
- Nancy 1.4.3
- Nancy.Hosting.Self 1.4.1

Comment: Why would you resolve the `NancyHost` from the container? It's not using the container at all?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why that call would fail with anything related to `HttpListener`. Nancy doesn't even touch `HttpListener` before calling `Start`.

Comment: I've simplified the use case just to demonstrate the problem. In reality I would inject configuration from the container. The errors I listed are actually when Start is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code "is waiting" on `Console.ReadLine();` and it is outside the `using`, the Autofac container is already disposed . Move `Console.ReadLine();` inside `using` to make it work.